# PHP FulCalendar - Citas no agendadas

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar

He estado haciendo un proyecto para agendar citas con FullCalendar y al momento de hacer click en la hora y dia me muestra el modal para confirmar la cita, la confirmo y no se me envia a la base. Este es mi codigo del MVC.

Soy nuevo en esto y quisiera que porfavor alguien me ayude a solucionarlo, se lo agradeceria mucho.

Muchas gracias por su colaboracion de antemano.

**CONTROLADOR**

```
public function EnviarCitaC(){
    if(isset($_POST["Did"])){

        $tablaBD = "citas";
        $Did = substr($_GET["url"], 7);
        $datosC = array("Did"=>$_POST["Did"], "Pid"=>$_POST["Pid"], "nyaC"=>$_POST["nyaC"], "Cid"=>$_POST["Cid"], "documentoC"=>$_POST["documentoC"], "fyhIC"=>$_POST["fyhIC"], "fyhFC"=>$_POST["fyhFC"]);
        $resultado = CitasM::EnviarCitaM($tablaBD, $datosC);
    }
}
```

**MODELO**

```
static public function EnviarCitaM($tablaBD, $datosC){
    $pdo = ConexionBD::cBD()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tablaBD (id_doctor, id_consultorio, id_paciente, nyaP, documento, inicio, fin) VALUES (:id_doctor, :id_consultorio, :id_paciente, :nyaP, :documento, :inicio, :fin)");
    $pdo -> bindParam(":id_doctor", $datosC["Did"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo -> bindParam(":id_consultorio", $datosC["Cid"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo -> bindParam(":id_paciente", $datosC["Pid"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo -> bindParam(":nyaP", $datosC["nyaC"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo -> bindParam(":documento", $datosC["documentoC"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo -> bindParam(":inicio", $datosC["fyhIC"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo -> bindParam(":fin", $datosC["fyhFC"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if($pdo->execute()){
        return true;
    }
    $pdo -> close();
    $pdo = null;
}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar la parte del código JS donde se realizan los eventos del fullCalendar.

Comment: También puedes hacer un `var_dump($_POST)` para mostrar que te esta regresando de tu js por favor.

Comment: El codigo que compartiste esta perfecto, tendrias que seguir las indicaciones de lo que te dijeron antes, y yo te diria que tambien verifiques los tipos de datos de la base de datos, y que compartas el codigo de los inputs html. Pero al parecer el error no está en el modelo ni en el controlador,

Comment: Agustin me podrias ayudar con alguna red social para contactarte porfavor.